# add a css class after click

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I would like to be able to add a class addclass when a user clicks the href element.  I am using coffeescript.  Any advice?

```
<div class="visual-tabs">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs event-type">
        <li>
            <a class="form-scores">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="form-scores">Test 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).on 'click', "#myTab .nav-tabs li a", (e) ->
  $(this).addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.nav-tabs` from your selector, it's searching for that as a child of `#myTab`. It's also a bit redundant, you're already selecting a unique ID.

```
$(document).on 'click', "#myTab li a", (e) ->
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your selector. By writing the selector the way you have it, you are looking for an element with the class `nav-tabs` that is a child of an element with the ID of `myTab`.

So, `"#myTab .nav-tabs li a"` needs to be`#myTab.nav-tabs li a` or simplified to `".nav-tabs li a"` or `"#myTab li a"`

The reason why this is happening is because the `#myTab` CSS selector is targeting the `ul` thereby causing it to look for an element with the class `nav-tabs` that is a child of that `ul` (which is not what you're intending).

That's why combining those two selectors fixes the problem (e.g. `#myTab.nav-tabs`). Doing that will cause it to look for any element with both of those classes, and then any `li` that is a child of it.